# How to check if location services are enabled for a particular app in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios7, location

I want to check `Location Service` is `on/off` for my application,because when I turn `locaiton Service to ON` but `application service is off` so` how can I check it by code.

Please help to solve my problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 15):

For those who are attempting to do this in swift.

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
    case .NotDetermined, .Restricted, .Denied:
        println("No access")
    case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        println("Access")
    default:
        println("...")
    }
} else {
    println("Location services are not enabled")
}
```

Comment: awsome keep it up :)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

In the locationManager:didFailWithError:,

Add this:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{


    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        NSLog(@"Enabled");

        if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
        {
             NSLog(@"Permission Denied");
        }
    }
 }
```